# WPF Pie chart palette disable random brushes regeneration

Tags: c#, wpf, charts

I have a pie chart, every time I update (**Re-assign to a new collection**) my **itemssource** the colors changes **randomly**, All I Want is to keep the first palette.

the pie chart is from `System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Charting` from the assembly
`System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.ToolKit`

Comment: add more details. what kind of pie chart. As far as i know there is no default piechart in wpf so please add some more information.

Comment: To [*ask a good question*](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), you generally need more than 2 sentences... if you had explained your situation better, we wouldn't all need to ask these questions: What do you mean by *update my `ItemsSource`*? Do you mean update the collection data bound to the `ItemsSource` property, or do you mean that you set a different collection object to data bind to it?

Comment: @Sheridan when I re-assign my itemssource to a new collection

Comment: Then simply *don't* do that... clear the old collection and add the new items into it, *keeping* the *same* `ItemsSource` object.

Comment: That's a little difficult, Beause i read directly from the DB and I have about a 3000 entry, and I do some filtering, grouping,..., which near to impossible with sqlserver, but the pie chart contains *Palette* property in which i couldn't find a solution !!!

Answer (score 1):

A quick research shows me that the `System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.ChartingChart.Chart` has a Property `Palette` which stores by default 15 different `ResourceDictionary` each section of the PieChart will use the next Colors (or Styles or whatever is strored in the Dictionary). If you want to keep the same Color you could add (15 - n) sections where n is the number of sections that was displayed. And then Change the Itemssource to whatever you want.

Comment: that's a nice idea, but its too hard in my case (undo-able) !